# import module with name in typescript

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I'm working at some web app, and I'm stucked.
I'm using **typescript**, **requirejs**, **qunit** (for UT). The test code is

```
import x = require("operations");
test("1==1", function () { ok(1 == 1), "1==1" });
```

it complies into

```
define(["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
});
test("1==1", function () { ok(1 == 1), "1==1" });
```

and throws

> Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: function (require,
>   exports)...

The problem is - loading some module with anonymous define(). I've managed to get the code work by changing "import" operator by pure requireJS define function like that:

```
define("operations", ["require", "exports"], function (require, exports) {
  test("1==1", function () { ok(1 == 1), "1==1"; });
});
test("1==1", function () { ok(1 == 1), "1==1" });
```

As you can see, I've named my module "operations" in define() function. It can fly, but I can't use advantages of Typescript because I've lost my classes and objects (for example, **x**). And of course I don't like this.

My question is: Is there any way to import external module with typescript with giving it (module) name. I mean - can we write **import** directive some way to compile it into

```
define("operations", ["require", "exports"], function(require, exports){...}
```

?

Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Well, even if I use x - I've recieve described error. More than - if I comment the test with x' using, I've got this error. The only way to avoid this error - is using define() directly. But it doesn't suit me.

Comment: shouldn't it be `import x from "operations"` without that require stuff? There are loaders like SystemJS that load under any syntax and unify it

Comment: thanks, Benjamin, but it is not so.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudio/archive/2015/04/20/using-requirejs-with-visual-studio.aspx - I need to use import and require. It is typescript.